# Visual Studio 2017: References are mentioned not being built while they are already built

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017, enterprise version. I'm working on a C# project, depending on several NuGet packages.

One of my references is mentioned being missing (there's a yellow triangle above the icon in the solution explorer). When I double-click on it, in order to see its contents in the object browser, I get following error message:

```
This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built.
Please ensure that the project is available and built.
```

You might think: "just restore the package (it's a NuGet package) and off you go", but the problem is that the message makes no sense:
In another project, I am using the exact same NuGet package as a reference, there everything is fine, and when I do a file/directory compare between that other project and my current one, WinMerge mentions both being equal. (Not only WinMerge, I also did a checksum comparison)

So my question is: what's the source of Visual Studio's `This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built.` error message? What's the source of the yellow triangle in Visual Studio's solution explorer (for NuGet packages)?

**Edit** (added: Visual Studio version)
For your information, I'm working with Visual Studio enterprise 2017, version 15.9.36.

Comment: what's the Target .NET Framework Version of both the Project. Right Click on Project and Properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I've found a workaround: I remove the references from the project and add them again, and it seems to work. Apparently there's some instability in Visual Studio reference handling.

Comment: Is the project in Source Control? You could have checked what changes happened before and after in the project file (.csproj)

Comment: In most cases, the path for reference assemblies will be incorrect and hence it doesn't work in different machines The `HintPath` for references in .csproj files should always be a relative path. Also, I have seen people adding the NuGet packages folder in Source Control which is completely wrong.  The packages. config is enough to say which all packages must be downloaded.

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar: the HintPath tags are all relative, but as you mention, the NuGet packages are all included in source control, which might be causing the mentioned problem.

Comment: Better fix it soon. If the version control on packages.config is lost. It will be difficult to fix all the references later.